# Failed to verify whole-file signature while rooting on Moto 2G XT1064

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g

First question on here. I've seen others with this verification problem but I couldn't find an answer for the Moto 2G XT1064 specifically. I've gone through all the prior steps, unlocking the bootloader, setting USB debugging to true, installed Moto 2G drivers and android drivers, and so forth. (However, the "OEM unlock" developer option doesn't exist on my Marshmallow 6.0).

Anyways, whenever I try to flash/install SuperSu.zip, I keep getting this error:

```
verifying update package...
E:failed to verify whole-file signature
E:signature verification failed
installation aborted.
```

It doesn't matter which SuperSu version I flash, 2.68 or 2.65. It still gets that error. I don't know how to get past the verification failure. Anyone have any clue? Thank you!

EDIT: I use titan-24.11.10-BR-boot.img

Comment: What's your current recovery? Post pics of your bootloader and recovery.

Comment: Try to get a custom recovery and try to flash it again...

Answer (score 2):

Your on Marshmallow, you need to do some extra steps...

First, install TWRP 3.0 or higher, or be able to boot it one time, and you need to have SuperSU 2.76 or 2.78 (even #'s are stable versions) on the device.

Start TWRP, go to Advanced - Terminal and enter

`echo SYSTEMLESS=true>>/data/.supersu` and press ENTER

Then exit and go back to home and Install SuperSU normally.

Comment: Sorry, Android noob. I installed the boot image, but how exactly do I "start" TWRP? Load recovery mode on my Moto 2G, or run a command prompt on my computer?

Comment: @CreativiTimothy Insulting me won't help you root your phone. The answer is you put the current TWRP img file on your PC in the fastboot directory, to start TWRP you can enter `fastboot boot twrp.img` or you can flash it with `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` and then start it from the bootloader. (replace "twrp.img" with the name of your actual twrp image file)

Comment: ????? I said I was an Android noob, not you. That's why I asked noobish questions like how to start TWRP. Okay, I see. Let me try that

Comment: @CreativiTimothy Sorry, I took your comment incorrectly and misunderstood your intent.

Comment: Okay, I installed the TWRP. How do I go to Advanced - Terminal? Is that on the computer CMD or on the Moto 2G?

Comment: @CreativiTimothy You start TWRP... if you flashed it, power off and enter the bootloader, then start recovery, this should start TWRP. In TWRP, press the Advanced button, then press the Terminal button. Once the terminal is open enter the command EXACTLY as shown in my answer. Then exit the terminal and press the Home button. Press Install and select the SuperSU zip file and flash it, you should notice a message about a systemless install occuring, once it completes reboot and enjoy your rooted device.

Comment: There isn't an advanced button. There is "Reboot system now" "Reboot to bootloader" and a couple other options, but not advanced. I'm not sure what you're referring to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45339/discussion-between-creativitimothy-and-acejavelin).

Comment: @CreativiTimothy Did you get it working? I posted in chat but you didn't respond... If you're not in a chat room SA doesn't notify of you new messages unless you turn on Desktop Notifications in the chat room.

Comment: Sorry, late reply. I just replied to the chatroom